# CarbonCopy to a gmail address doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, sdk, docusignapi

I'm using a DocuSign Java SDK and need the functionality of CarbonCopy as I need to send every document to a person within our company other than a Signer.

So when I use the gmail address for the Signer the email is sent. But when I use the gmail address for the CarbonCopy recipient the email is never sent and I do not get an error. The envelope id is returned as if everything went fine.

Is there anything that I'm missing? Is it possible to make that work?

```
     // login call available off the AuthenticationApi
     AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();

     // login has some optional parameters we can set
     AuthenticationApi.LoginOptions loginOps = authApi.new LoginOptions();
     loginOps.setApiPassword("true");
     loginOps.setIncludeAccountIdGuid("true");
     LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.login(loginOps);

     // note that a given user may be a member of multiple accounts
     List<LoginAccount> loginAccounts = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts();

     String accountId = loginAccounts.get(0).getAccountId();

     Path path = Paths.get(sFilePath);
     byte[] PDFContents = Files.readAllBytes(path);

     // Create an envelope that will store the document(s), field(s), and recipient(s)
     EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
     envDef.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document sent from Java SDK)");

     // Add a document to the envelope
     Document doc = new Document();  
     String base64Doc = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(PDFContents);
     doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
     doc.setName("MaterialRequisition.pdf");    // can be different from actual file name
     doc.setDocumentId("1");

     List<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>();
     docs.add(doc);
     envDef.setDocuments(docs);

     // add a recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email we used above
     Signer signer = new Signer();
     signer.setEmail(sApproverEmail);
     signer.setName(sApproverName);
     signer.setRecipientId("1");

     CarbonCopy cc = new CarbonCopy();
     cc.setEmail(sCCEmail);
     cc.setName(sCCName);
     cc.setRecipientId("2");

     // create a signHere tab somewhere on the document for the signer to sign
     // default unit of measurement is pixels, can be mms, cms, inches also
     SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
     signHere.setDocumentId("1");
     signHere.setPageNumber("1");
     signHere.setRecipientId("1");
     signHere.setXPosition("100");
     signHere.setYPosition("710");

     // Can have multiple tabs, so need to add to envelope as a single element list
     List<SignHere> signHereTabs = new ArrayList<SignHere>();      
     signHereTabs.add(signHere);
     Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
     tabs.setSignHereTabs(signHereTabs);
     signer.setTabs(tabs);

     // add recipients (in this case a single signer) to the envelope
     envDef.setRecipients(new Recipients());
     envDef.getRecipients().setSigners(new ArrayList<Signer>());
     envDef.getRecipients().getSigners().add(signer);
     envDef.getRecipients().getCarbonCopies().add(cc);

     // send the envelope by setting |status| to "sent". To save as a draft set to "created"
     envDef.setStatus("sent");

     // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
     EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

     // call the createEnvelope() API to send the signature request!
     EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
     logger.debug("Envelope Id "+ envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId());

     // Delete the PDF file that Logi generated
     Files.delete(path);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CarbonCopy recipients will receive email only when the envelope gets completed by all the parties based on the recipient’s order. Have a look at the Carbon Copies Recipient description in this [link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Carbon%20Copies%20Recipient.htm).

Debug the code and make sure whether CarbonCopy values gets added inside the envDef.getRecipients().getCarbonCopies() before it hits the createEnvelope and when the full envelope process gets completed by the signer thereafter a copy will be sent to the carbon copy recipient mail address, to make sure of that sign into the CarbonCopy recipient email address an email must be received along with completed document where you can only view the document..

Comment: That's very strange, because when I flipped the email addresses and made gmail my signer and my company email my CarbonCopy I received Both emails without having to sign the document first.

Comment: Have you tried setting the routing order for Signer as 1 i.e, signer.RoutingOrder = "1" and  for CarbonCopy as 2 i.e, cc.RoutingOrder ="2"...

Comment: Hi Ram. Tried setting the Routing Order finally. Set the signer to 1 and Carbon Copy to 2 and no email. However, like you said, once the document was signed the email did come in to Carbon Copy so that will have to do for now. Thank you.